Select non-const method based on lamba signature with auto arguments
I have the following problem where an incorrect method is selected because of lambda's auto arguments.
See the following example:
template <class T, class FunctionT>
concept ValidNonConstSignature = requires(FunctionT exec_fn, T& value) { exec_fn(value); };

template <class T, class FunctionT>
concept ValidConstSignature = requires(FunctionT exec_fn, const T& value) { exec_fn(value); };

class Foo {
public:
  template <class FunctionT> requires ValidNonConstSignature<int, FunctionT>
  auto
  getBar(FunctionT callback) {
    return callback(m_abc);
  }

  template <class FunctionT> requires ValidConstSignature<int, FunctionT>
  auto
  getBar(FunctionT callback) const {
    return callback(m_abc);
  }

private:
  int m_abc {};
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    
    foo.getBar([](int& abc){ return abc++; });
    foo.getBar([](const int& abc){ return abc++; });   // correct compiler error: increment of read-only reference ‘abc’
    
    foo.getBar([](auto& abc){ return abc++; });        // incorrect compiler error: increment of read-only reference ‘abc’
    foo.getBar([](const auto& abc){ return abc++; });  // correct compiler error: increment of read-only reference ‘abc’

    return 0;
}

Because of the existence of getBar(FunctionT callback) const, the foo.getBar([](auto& abc){ return abc++; }); fails to compile.
If the getBar(FunctionT callback) const method is removed, foo.getBar([](auto& abc){ return abc++; }); compiles just fine.
Is there a way to somehow enhance the concepts to correctly select the non-const method? My initial idea was to get argument types via another template from the passed callback, but the compiler complained about incomplete type when passed lamda with auto in it.

When you use auto with reference, it can be deduced to const reference (unlike when auto is without reference). Therefore, the problem is not in your concepts but auto& can be deduced to be both const int& and int&.

[](auto& abc){ return abc++; } is not SFINAE friendly, you might requires that !std::is_const_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(abc)>> Demo.

Define ValidNonConstSignature in terms of ValidConstSignature: concept ValidNonConstSignature = ValidConstSignature<T, F> or requires. That makes ValidNonConstSignature more specific than ValidConstSignature. Better option would be the new explicit this syntax: decltype(auto) Foo::getbar(this auto& self, auto&& f) requires std::invocable<decltype(f), decltype(self.m_abc)> { return f(self.m_abc)};

@Red.Wave: Issue comes before: evaluating ValidConstSignature<int, decltype([](auto& abc) { return abc++; })> triggers hard error, and not substitution failure.

@Red.Wave A or B is less specific than A, not more

Mostly all ValidConstSignature functions would be a ValidNonConstSignature (the exceptions are for the (template) functions rejecting explicitly non-const ref), so with non-const Foo, the ValidNonConstSignature overload would be an exact match.

@Red.Wave thank you for mentioning the explicit this. I did manage to get it working with explicit this, however it requires c++23 which I sadly cannot use.
I achieved something with my concepts and std::invocable, just need to figure out why is it working first.

@WeijunZhou logic games are tricky. I always need a few iterations before getting it right.

So it seems I has getting ahead of myself with the concepts. Only 1 is required and the compiler seems to do the rest: https://godbolt.org/z/eszGEx61P I feel stupid now for immediately going for the complicated solution...

Nevermind, it causes another issue https://godbolt.org/z/sTzrfqc6f

nonconst foo may call const getBar where the foo itself becomes const https://godbolt.org/z/1YTsG6evd

[](auto& abc) { return abc++; } is not SFINAE friendly, so instantiating it with [auto = int] would produce hard error and not a substitution failure.
If you are ok to make your functions not SFINAE friendly neither, you can "delay" the check with static_assert:
class Foo
{
public:
  template <class FunctionT> 
  auto getBar(FunctionT callback) {
    static_assert(ValidNonConstSignature<int, FunctionT>);
    return callback(m_abc);
  }

  template <class FunctionT>
  auto getBar(FunctionT callback) const {
    static_assert(ValidConstSignature<int, FunctionT>);
    return callback(m_abc);
  }

private:
  int m_abc {};
};

Demo

While this is not a solution that I will be using in the end, I feel that it is the most correct answer to what I have originally asked. As a bonus the static asserts will allow to provide easier to read context.

If C++23 is not available to you, you can emulate deducing this like this:
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class FunctionT>
concept ValidSignature =
    requires(FunctionT exec_fn, T& value) { exec_fn(value); };

class Foo
{
  public:
    template <class This, class FunctionT>
    requires std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<This>, Foo>
             && ValidSignature<std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<This>, 
                                                  const int, int>, FunctionT>
    friend auto getBar(This& foo, FunctionT callback) {
        return callback(foo.m_abc);
    }

  private:
    int m_abc{};
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    const Foo foo_const;

    getBar(foo, [](int& abc) { return abc++; });
    // getBar(foo, [](const int& abc) { return abc++; }); // does not compile

    getBar(foo, [](auto& abc) { return abc++; });
    // getBar(foo, [](const auto& abc) { return abc++; }); // does not compile

    // getBar(foo_const, [](int& abc) { return abc++; }); // does not compile
    getBar(foo_const, [](const int& abc) { return abc; });

    // getBar(foo_const, [](auto& abc) { return abc++; }); // does not compile
    getBar(foo_const, [](const auto& abc) { return abc; });
}

Note that you don't strictly need std::conditional_t<std::is_const_v<This>, const int, int> but then the hard error will occur at a different place.

After Red.Wave suggested the explicit this, I have more or less settled on this approach that would reuse the implementation (similar to patrick's example, but a little cleaner):
C++20:
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T, class FunctionT>
concept ValidSignature =
    requires(FunctionT exec_fn, T& value) { exec_fn(value); };

class Foo {
   public:
    template <class FunctionT>
    auto getBar(FunctionT&& callback) {
        return getBarImpl(*this, std::forward<FunctionT>(callback));
    }

    template <class FunctionT>
    auto getBar(FunctionT&& callback) const {
        return getBarImpl(*this, std::forward<FunctionT>(callback));
    }

   private:
    template <class Self, class FunctionT>
    static auto getBarImpl(Self& self, FunctionT&& callback)
        requires ValidSignature<decltype(self.m_abc), FunctionT>
    {
        constexpr bool IsConst = std::is_const_v<Self>;
        if constexpr (IsConst) {
            // called from const
        } else {
            // called from non-const
        }

        return std::forward<FunctionT>(callback)(self.m_abc);
    }

    int m_abc{};
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    const Foo foo_const;

    foo.getBar([](int& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo.getBar([](const int& abc) { return abc; });

    foo.getBar([](auto& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo.getBar([](const auto& abc) { return abc; });

    // foo_const.getBar([](int& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo_const.getBar([](const int& abc) { return abc; });

    // foo_const.getBar([](auto& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo_const.getBar([](const auto& abc) { return abc; });
}

For future travelers, this is how you could do it with C++23:
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <class T, class FunctionT>
concept ValidSignature =
    requires(FunctionT exec_fn, T& value) { exec_fn(value); };

class Foo {
   public:
    template <class Self, class FunctionT>
    auto getBar(this Self& self, FunctionT&& callback)
        requires ValidSignature<decltype(self.m_abc), FunctionT>
    {
        constexpr bool IsConst = std::is_const_v<Self>;
        if constexpr (IsConst) {
            // called from const
        } else {
            // called from non-const
        }

        return std::forward<FunctionT>(callback)(self.m_abc);
    }

   private:
    int m_abc{};
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    const Foo foo_const;

    foo.getBar([](int& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo.getBar([](const int& abc) { return abc; });

    foo.getBar([](auto& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo.getBar([](const auto& abc) { return abc; });

    // foo_const.getBar([](int& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo_const.getBar([](const int& abc) { return abc; });

    // foo_const.getBar([](auto& abc) { return abc++; });
    foo_const.getBar([](const auto& abc) { return abc; });
}


decltype(self.m_abc) will not give you const int but int!

@patrick why is that a problem? self.m_abc is still const when called from const method, which will not compile if your lambda tries to modify it as a reference.

What I am saying is, you might have as well write ValidSignature<int, decltype(callback)> instead of ValidSignature<decltype(self.m_abc), decltype(callback)> because decltype(self.m_abc) will never give you const int.

Extra parenthesis decltype((self.m_abc)) resolves the issue, you will have const int& or int&.

The C++20 way is not SFINAE friendly BTW

If you actually need the types of the parameters (as you do here), writing auto is not actually any terser. For instance, if you declared template <class Self>, you could just write Self instead of std::remove_reference_t<decltype(self)>

@Barry You're right, thanks for noticing this. I will update the answer to remove some of the autos.

The key problem is that your lambda is not SFINAE-friendly. The idea is that lambdas with auto& parameters might not behave predictably with concepts, overloads, or template constraints because lambdas does not naturally reject certain types like const& through substitution failure.
Type mismatch problems usually are easy to explain but not this one, I will try to make it clear.
This is your ValidNonConstSignature concept
template <class T, class FunctionT>
concept ValidNonConstSignature = requires(FunctionT exec_fn, T& value) { exec_fn(value); };

Inside the requires clause, you have (FunctionT exec_fn, T& value) { exec_fn(value) i.e. the lambda is expected to accept an int& which is totally fine until you instantiate the concept with T = int. The type that the concept uses to validate the lambda becomes confusing because T = int but the requires clause says exec_fn(int& value) and this is the root of the problem.
The concept is instantiated for T = int but when it checks the lambda signature, it expects the lambda to work with int& and that's why I've started the answer with mentioning that your lambda is not SFINAE-friendly.
We can't say that following the same pattern will always lead to a type mismatch. If this is the case we would either fix the language or avoid it because we know that it won't work 100% of the time. But actually i can say that this can lead to a type mismatch depending on how the lambda is defined especially if you use auto& in your lambda, which behaves slightly differently due to type deduction rules.
To sum it all up, let's take a look at your lambda
foo.getBar([](auto& abc) { return abc++; });


The lambda parameter is deduced as int& but your concept was
constrained with ValidNonConstSignature<int, FunctionT>. This
mismatch confuses the compiler because the constraint expects a
different instantiation (int vs int&).

The auto& deduction leads to the compiler reporting that the lambda
signature doesn’t match the required concept, even though auto&
should logically work.


An easy fix for this is simply instantiating the concept with int& instead of int.
This ensures that reference semantics are properly preserved and when the following lambda is passed:
foo.getBar([](auto& abc) { return abc++; });

The compiler knows that auto is deduced to int& and this matches the int& in the ValidNonConstSignature constraint, so the concept check succeeds.
Here is the concept instantiation changes.
class Foo {
public:
  template <class FunctionT> requires ValidNonConstSignature<int&, FunctionT>
  auto
  getBar(FunctionT callback) {
    return callback(m_abc);
  }

  template <class FunctionT> requires ValidConstSignature<int&, FunctionT>
  auto
  getBar(FunctionT callback) const {
    return callback(m_abc);
  }

private:
  int m_abc {};
};


It also works only with 1 concept and without int&: https://godbolt.org/z/eszGEx61P . However, now the next step for me is try reused the non-const method which is another issue in itself: https://godbolt.org/z/YPYrsP958

@FrogTheFrog My bad, I've noticed that after posting the answer. I'm working on it and i will update it once i have a solution

No problem, thanks for helping! I do have a "solution" that I don't know how I feel about it though... https://godbolt.org/z/qsrszY5EK

@FrogTheFrog Usually, non-const version is implemented in terms of const version, not the opposite. It is much safer to const_cast from non-const to const than the opposite. It is also more sensible to narrow down the function istead of broadening it.

@FrogTheFrog I don't know if its gonna help or not but this is my take. I was able to static_cast the entity to const to invoke the const instance when a the lambda sig. contains const. But the auto& issue is still there. Maybe combining my trial with yours will solve the problem https://godbolt.org/z/ejnPdh3e9

The problem with auto& is that it is decided at the compile time whether it's const ref or not (auto& has a superposition of both apparently). Bringing quantum mechanics to c++... Anyways, I have already resolved it to a satisfactory level and also posted the answer myself.

It took me a little while to see it, because at first I was thinking
of checking for ambiguous function calls to determine the const-ness of the given callable. But then I realized it can be done in a much simpler way.
The problem is that a generic lambda needs to have its templated call operator instantiated in order to check for its invocability. Since this instantiation doesn't happen in the immediate context of the concept being validated, the result is a hard-error. Simply checking if a [](auto&){} can be invoked with an int const& results in the instantiation of an operator()(int const&) function, of which the argument is then expected to follow the rules of being const.
What we can do instead is to check for the invocability with just a plain int argument. In case a [](auto&){} needs to be checked, its templated call operator will now be instantiated as operator()(int&), matching the const-ness of its original template argument. Checking a [](auto const&){} leads to a operator()(int const&) being instantiated, still matching the const-ness of the provided lambda.
#include <concepts>

class Foo {
public:
    auto getBar(std::invocable<int&> auto callback)
    { return callback(m_abc); }

    auto getBar(std::invocable<int> auto callback) const
    { return callback(m_abc); }

private:
    int m_abc{};
};

When the callable takes an int& parameter, it doesn't accept rvalue ints, since an lvalue-reference can't bind to an rvalue. And this is exactly what the concept std::invocable checks for. The table below shows which kind of callable satisfies std::invocable for each given argument type.



Callable (now as F)
int
int&
int const&




[](int){}
✅
✅
✅


[](int&){}
❌
✅
❌


[](int const&){}
✅
✅
✅



So, the getBar function of a Foo that is non-const can accept all 3 of those callables, since we constrain its template argument with std::invocable<F, int&>. Whereas, the getBar function of a Foo that is const, can only accept a callable that takes an int or an int const&, since this overload is constrained with std::invocable<F, int>.
The only difference to that table compared to generic lambdas (when replacing int with auto), is that a callable constrained with std::invocable<F, int const&> would also accept a [](auto&){}, due to the type-deduction rules. However, this doesn't really have any bearing, as each non-const and const-qualified getBar overload is only constrained with std::invocable<F, int&> and std::invocable<F, int>, respectively.

If you also wish to support callables that work with rvalue-references, you'd have to provide the correct ref-qualified overloads to getBar to make sure the value category of the expression where data-member m_abc is accessed changes accordingly:
class Foo {
public:
    auto getBar(std::invocable<int&> auto callback) &
    { return callback(m_abc); }

    auto getBar(std::invocable<int&&> auto callback) &&
    { return callback(static_cast<int&&>(m_abc)); }

    auto getBar(std::invocable<int> auto callback) const&
    { return callback(m_abc); }

    auto getBar(std::invocable<int> auto callback) const&&
    { return callback(static_cast<int const&&>(m_abc)); }

private:
    int m_abc{};
};

C++23's deducing-this feature would allow us to achieve the same goal without having to write all of these overloads:
template<typename Self, typename F>
requires std::invocable<F, int>
    or std::invocable<F, int&>
auto getBar(this Self&& self, F callback) {
    using self_unref = std::remove_reference_t<Self>;
    if constexpr (std::is_const_v<self_unref>) { /* ... */ }
    else { /* ... */ }
    return callback(std::forward_like<Self>(self.m_abc));
}

Demo
